# Conflicting Types Error

Tags: c, types

when i run the following code, i get the error

```
 problem1.c:136:6: error: conflicting types for 'strcspn' 
   int strcspn( char * str, char * reject )
```

I'm not sure why I am getting the conflicting types error.
here is the code:

```
int strcspn( char * str, char * reject ) 
{

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i ++)
    {       for (int j = 0; j < strlen(reject); j++)
                if ( *(str + i) == *(reject + j) )
                return counter;
        counter++;
    }

return counter;

}


void main ()
{


char * str1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
char * str2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
sprintf(str1, "abc123");
sprintf(str2, "d2");
printf("%d\n", strcspn(str1, str2)); 

}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally redefining a standard string library call?

Comment: "here is the code:"  --> or is it "here is most of the code except for the `#include` files portion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lowtech already said in his answer, you should avoid to redefine names of the functions in your C programs that are already taken.

Any way there are some issue with your program which you should know.

> 1) strlen's return type is **size_t** and not int.
>   2) main
>   should be at least **int main(void){}**
>   3) there is no need to cast
>   malloc, its return type is void*
>   4) and most important one, you
>   should always free what you malloc.

Take a look here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int strcspn_ss( char * str, char * reject ){
    int counter = 0;
    size_t i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i ++){
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(reject); j++)
                if ( *(str + i) == *(reject + j) )
                return counter;
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}


int main (void){

    char * str1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    char * str2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    sprintf(str1, "abc123");
    sprintf(str2, "d2");
    printf("%d\n", strcspn_ss(str1, str2));

    free(str1);
    free(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
like cad said in his comment, there is an Important thing which you should know, that if you declare a variable inside a Function or used as parameter doesn't affect the function strcspn, please see the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(int strcspn){
    printf("strcspn = %d\n",strcspn);
}


int main (void){
    int strcspn = 10;
    foo(strcspn);
    return 0;
}
```

Which is Legal.

Comment: Could you please clarify the "token" part?

Comment: @cad what do you mean ?

Comment: In `void foo(int strcspn) {}` the `strcspn` won't cause harm, although it is a token.

Comment: You do realize that you speak about function parameter? What's your point and what has to do with this Question/Answer ?

Comment: I read "[...] redefine names of the functions in your C programs that are already token." as any occurence of `strcspn` is forbidden. Your added code example isn't necessary. I'll edit and you can roll back if you're not content.

Comment: @cad Please show me where the Standard says , that my edited part is forbidden in C. **int strcspn = 10;** is Legal and is not forbidden, maybe you mean to be avoided.

Comment: @Cad you can correct my English, but please never delete some part of my Answers.

Comment: About 'token', it's a lot of confusion caused by a typo: the first line of the answer has 'token' where it should say 'taken'.

Comment: @MicroVirus Thank you Fix it.

Comment: "but please never delete some part of my Answers" That's not really an issue. As I said, roll back and your fine.

Comment: @MicroVirus Holy crap, I didn't realize that! Thanks man/woman. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`strcspn` is declared in `<strings.h>`. Looks like you somehow have included that header and then trying to redefine `strcspn` differently from header file definition. In my `<strings.h>` it is defined as

```
 size_t strcspn(const char *s, const char *reject);
```

Comment: @cad thanks for editing, it does look better this way