# error: conflicting types for ‘fmin’

Tags: c, compilation

I have a problem trying to alter a program that basically works. I got this bunch of programs from a (now distant) friend of mine a while ago and they should be working fine. However when I try to compile the presumably working code I get an error.

The programs use libraries nr.h and nrutil.h from the Numerical recipes and both contain the declaration *fmin*.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "recipes/nrutil.h"
#include "recipes/nr.h"


float s(float t, float omega);
float c(float t, float omega);
void DFT(int dir, int N, float** mat);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i,j;
    int N=100;
    float** mat=matrix(1,2,0,N);
    float tmp;

    for (i=0;i<=N;i++){
        tmp=s((1.0*i)/N,1.0);
        if (tmp>=0.5) mat[1][i]=0.5;
        else if (tmp<=0.5) mat[1][i]=-0.5;
        else mat[1][i]=tmp;
        mat[2][i]=0.0;
    }

    DFT(1,N,mat);
    DFT(-1,N,mat);
    FILE* fout=fopen("test.dat","w+");
/*  
    for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
        fprintf(fout,"%d %0.16e %0.16e %0.16e\n",i
                                                                                      ,mat[1][i]
                                                                                        ,mat[2][i]
                                                                                        ,s((1.0*i)/N,8.5)-mat[1][i]);
*/

    for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
        fprintf(fout,"%e %0.16e %0.16e %0.16e %d %0.16e\n",(i-N/2)*1.0/N
                                                                                                          ,mat[1][i]
                                                                                                            ,mat[2][i]
                                                                                                            ,sqrt(SQR(mat[1][i])+SQR(mat[2][i]))
                                                                                                            ,i
                                                                                                            ,s((1.0*i)/N,1.0));

    fclose(fout);

    free_matrix(mat,1,2,0,N);
    return (0);
}


float s(float t, float omega)
{
    return (sin(2*M_PI*omega*t));
}

float c(float t, float omega)
{
    return (cos(2*M_PI*omega*t));
}

void DFT(int dir, int N, float** mat)
{
    int i,k;
    float arg;
    float cosarg,sinarg;
    float** mat2=matrix(1,2,0,N);

    if (dir==1){    
        for (i=-N/2;i<=N/2;i++){
            mat2[1][i+N/2]=0;
            mat2[2][i+N/2]=0;
            arg=-dir*2.0*M_PI*(float)i/(float)N;
            for (k=0;k<N;k++){
                cosarg=cos(k*arg);
                sinarg=sin(k*arg);
                mat2[1][i+N/2]+=mat[1][k]*cosarg-mat[2][k]*sinarg;
                mat2[2][i+N/2]+=mat[1][k]*sinarg+mat[2][k]*cosarg;
            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<=N;i++){
            mat[1][i]=mat2[1][i]/(float)N;
            mat[2][i]=mat2[2][i]/(float)N;
        }
    } 
    else{
        for (k=0;k<=N;k++){
            mat2[1][k]=0;
            mat2[2][k]=0;
            arg=-dir*2.0*M_PI*(float)k/(float)N;
            for (i=-N/2;i<=N/2;i++){
                cosarg=cos(i*arg);
                sinarg=sin(i*arg);
                mat2[1][k]+=mat[1][i+N/2]*cosarg-mat[2][i+N/2]*sinarg;
                mat2[2][k]+=mat[1][i+N/2]*sinarg+mat[2][i+N/2]*cosarg;
            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<=N;i++){
            mat[1][i]=mat2[1][i];
            mat[2][i]=mat2[2][i];
        }
    }

    free_matrix(mat2,1,2,0,N);
}
```

Now when I try to compile the program I get a error message:

```
 In file included from nal01a.c:12:0: recipes/nr.h:188:7: error:
 conflicting types for ‘fmin’  float fmin(float x[]);

 In file included from nal01a.c:10:0: /usr/include/math.h:289:15: note: previous declaration of ‘fmin’ was
 here  extern double fmin _PARAMS((double, double));
```

The original programmer was able to run the same program but I can't compile it. What could be the cause? I'm trying to compile it with Cygwin.

Many thanks in advance .

Comment: Similar problem (only the function name different) [can be found **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572503/conflicting-types-error).

Answer (score 1):

`fmin` is a pre-defined function in header `math.h` (which takes arguments as `double`).

What is happening is that you have a user  defined function in your header file named `"recipes/nr.h"`  which has a function named `fmin` but with a different signature.

Therefore , the error by compiler . Change name of your function in your header file and the error should resolve.